# Couldn't capture volume key events in Android TV Box from Android version 8.1 on wards

Tags: android, android-tv

We have Android TV (ATV) box running on Android version 8.1 and above. We need to get key events for volume keys when pressed from ATV remote. Unfortunately we couldn't get volume key events from Android version 8.1. But we can get volume key events from Android version Nougat 7.0 box.
Question : How I need to capture volume key events in Android TV box versions 8.1 and 9 [pie] ?

We have tried following callback API `onKeyDown()`, `onKeyUp()`, `dispatchKeyEvent()`, `onKeyLongPress()` and `onKeyEvent()` in activity class.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){

  Log.d(TAG,"Key code pressed:" + event.getKeycode);
}
```

Expected output
Key code pressed :25
Key code pressed: 24

Actual output `onkeydown` not get triggered for volume keys
[see photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NlTv.jpg).

Comment: It might be the case that another Activity or fragment handles the keyCodes before it even reaches the part where you want to handle it. Have you ever tried to catch the keys in any other class?

Comment: Also I can suggest you test by sending keyevents through adb so that you know if it's not just some RC specific problem. Such as `adb shell input keyevent 24`

Comment: Thank you Faith for your suggestion. We tried input event 24 but not received keycode in the application. also we tried inputevent 19 (UP arrow) then we got keycode keycode_dpad_up.